is Romans 14:5 a command or more along the lines of a "concession"?
I've been wrestling a lot with the content of Romans 14. One of the key texts I'm confused with is Romans 14:5. I've typically understood this text to be indicating that Paul is basically making a command here about convictions. In other words, Paul is saying that even though people have different convictions, they must be fully convinced that what they are doing is right. So Paul's command is focused on the necessity of certainty about one's conviction.
I'm confused though, if Paul is making this kind of command, how could it be possible that two people can come to certainty about contradictory positions? Or is Paul endorsing that two people can both be fully convinced about something, but only one of them is actually right (e.g. that it is truly right or wrong to eat shrimp)? Why then would Paul tell them to be fully convinced about contradictory positions when they can't both be right? This "command" sense could be the right interpretation, but I'm confused about its implications.
But I was considering another interpretation of what Paul is really doing in Romans 14:5. Is it more of command to be willing to compromise rather than a command that people must be fully certain before they act?
For example, in the NIV and NASB, Romans 14:5b sounds more like a command:

One person considers one day more sacred than another; another
considers every day alike. Each of them should be fully convinced
in their own mind. (Romans 14:5, NIV)
One person values one day over another, another values every day the
same. Each person must be fully convinced in his own mind. (Romans
14:5, NASB)

But compare this with translations like the YLT or CSB, which sound more like the "concession" concept

One doth judge one day above another, and another doth judge every day
[alike]; let each in his own mind be fully assured. (Romans 14:5,
YLT)
One person judges one day to be more important than another day.
Someone else judges every day to be the same. Let each one be
fully convinced in his own mind. (Romans 14:5, CSB)

If a different sense is understood, Paul’s command here is not that people must be fully convinced, but rather it is to let people be fully convinced? In other words, would the text basically carry the sense of---stop quarreling over your differences on these disputable matters, and live peacefully with one another (Romans 14:19), and allow people to hold to their convictions without slandering one another (Romans 14:3-4, notice that these texts directly proceed Romans 14:5). Of course, this kind of desire on Paul's part for peace in the community is true on either interpretation, but does it help clarify what is meant in Romans 14:5?
This may also relate to Romans 14:22, which says,

“The faith that you have, keep between yourself and God. Blessed
is the one who has no reason to pass judgment on himself for what he
approves” (Romans 14:22, ESV).

If this other interpretation of Romans 14:5 is right, Paul is not demanding that people have doubtless certainty about their positions, but is advocating for a peaceful acceptance of people’s convictions so that the body can live in peace and community rather than division?

The original Greek states that 'one esteems one day above another and one esteems every day'. That is to say that one holds one day special and another sees every day as special. And they must accept one another's view and practice. I don't see why that should be a problem to you. The translation 'every day the same' (the second viewpoint) is incorrect.

I doubt that ‘let’ implies a concession; to me it seems more like a requirement (as per the ‘should’ and ‘must’ versions), especially in the archaic English that old translations use and some modern ones emulate.

The context of Romans 14:2-3, preceding Romans 14:5, focuses on dietary practices. Traditional Jews adhere to Kosher food laws, while Gentiles don't. Consequently, in a church comprising both Jews and Gentiles, differing eating practices lead to issues. Furthermore, Jews observe the Sabbath, which is unfamiliar to the Gentiles, leading to additional complications. This is likely what Romans 14:5 refers to, as Jews consider the Sabbath more sacred than other days, while faithful Gentiles may view every day as holy.
It is essential to understand that Paul is not asking believers to compromise, but to accept each other (Romans 14:1). Arguments over disputable matters can cause those with weaker faith to stumble (Romans 14:13). Everyone should hold unwaveringly to their belief in worshipping God without judging others, as God is the ultimate judge, as stated by Paul in Romans 14:4:

Who are you to judge someone else’s servant? To their own master, servants stand or fall. And they will stand, for the Lord is able to make them stand.

Ultimately, faith, devotion, and humility before God matter most; rituals are secondary.

In other words: we should accept and support one another, and not take minor differences of custom as a cause for argument or disharmony?

@gidds - You are correct. However, we should be aware of the term "sound doctrine" that Paul emphasized in 2 Tim 4:3, Titus 1:9 and Titus 2:1. Paul would never comprise on this.

Paul is saying this people should make decisions for themselves on disputable matters, even though they should not fight with others about them.  This is in stark contrast to people looking at disputable matters and just checking out intellectually.  He does not want people to think "There are multiple interpretations, therefore I am going to ignore the issue entirely and just assume that nothing is true."  He is giving full permission to intellectually grapple with these disputable matters and live one's life based on how one believes these disputable matters are answered.
This follows with multiple other places where the Bible requires that people firstly act with love, and use facts/theories/logic only inside that context.  (1 Corinthians 13:1-2)

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

The original Greek states that 'one esteems one day above another and one esteems every day'.
That is to say that one holds one day special and another sees every day as special. And they must accept one another's view and practice.
I don't see why that should be a problem to you.
The translation 'every day the same' (the second viewpoint) is incorrect.

ος μεν κρινει ημεραν παρ ημεραν ος δε κρινει πασαν ημεραν εκαστος εν τω ιδιω νοι πληροφορεισθω [TR Stephanus, Elzevir, Beza and Scrivener all identical]


One judges a day above a day another judges every day [Englishman's Greek New Testament Interlinear Literal 1870]

Some prefer to treat every day as a sabbath of rest in Christ.
And who is going to find fault with that ?

"Come unto me...and ye shall find rest unto your souls".  There is a one day a week body rest and there is ever present soul rest.  +1

I think you've missed the point of the question entirely. OP is confused about whether the verse suggests that two contradictory viewpoints can both be valid - not about whether one of the viewpoints is x or y. I think previous comment goes someway to linking your answer to the actual question by suggesting that the two viewpoints are not even contradictory. But I think this comment also fails to answer the spirit of the question which is about practical dynamics between church members.

@Hmwat I suggest you contribute your answer to the question, then.

I'm going to answer strictly about the linguistics of the matter, since that is the only part that interests me.
I think you're being confused by the word "let", thinking of it like "let me have some cake", or "let Sally play with the doll". But the word "let" can also (especially historically) be used as a third-person imperative, a sort of command for someone other than the listener to do something, and that is what we see here in the original Greek:

ἕκαστος ἐν τῷ ἰδίῳ νοῒ πληροφορείσθω

The base form of the word πληροφορείσθω is πληροφορέω. πληροφορέω can be translated as "convince" or "assure". Now, the base form ends with -έω, so we can look at a verb table to try to find out what the changed form -είσθω is. We find it in the second table, "Present: -ῶ, -οῦμαι (Contracted)".
We see in the table that it is the present third-person mediopassive singular imperative form of the verb. Third person means the doer is someone other than the speaker or listener; mediopassive means the doer is doing it to themself or having it done to them by someone else; singular means there is only one doer; imperative means it's a command. Put it all together and it means something like "[he/she/it] must be convinced".
So the form "let" in some translations does not appear to be concessive at all; this is just a quirk of language change. The words "should" or "must" convey the intended sense less ambiguously in Modern English.
